# Cannot iterate through a list while I iterate through a list of lists

Tags: r

The input is a list of lists.  Please see below. The file names is a list containing as many names as there are lists in the list (`name1`, `name2`, `name3`).
Each name is appended to the path: `path/name1` - `path/name2` - `path/name3`

The program iterates through the list containing the paths as it iterates through the list of lists and prints the paths with their file names.  I would expect for the output to be `path/name1` - `path/name2` - `path/name3`.  However I get the output below.  Please see OUTPUT *after* INPUT

**INPUT**

```
[[1]]
[1] "150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt"   "160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
[3] "JF_160426_Dep2Plas_ctryp_Gpep_SIDtargFULL__PSMs.txt"       "JF_160426_Dep2Plas_tryp_Gpep_SIDtarg-(06)_PSMs.txt"       

[[2]]
[1] "150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt"   "160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
[3] "JF_160426_Dep2Plas_ctryp_Gpep_SIDtargFULL__PSMs.txt"      

[[3]]
[1] "150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt"   
"160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
```

**OUTPUT**

I would expect for the output to be `path/nam1`  - `path/name2`   - `path/name3`

```
[1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/name1.tsv", 
[1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/name2.tsv", 
[1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/name3.tsv".
```

However I get the output below:

```
[1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/name1.tsv"
```

I cannot understand why I cannot iterate through the list of paths with the file name while iterating through the list of lists.  I hope this helps to clarify the problem.  Could anyone help with this?

I have analyzed each statement using printing and every thing works fine except for the output of the code below

```
for (i in 1:length(lc)) { 

    for (j in 1:length(lc[[i]])) { # fetch and read files
        if (j==1) {
            newFile <- paste(dataFnsDir, lc[[i]][j], sep="/")
            newFile <- tryCatch(read.delim(newFile, header = TRUE, sep = '/'), error=function(e) NULL)
            newFile<- tryCatch(newFile, error=function(e) data.frame())
            print(tmpFn[i])
        } else {
            newFile <- paste(dataFnsDir, lc[[i]][j], sep="/")
            newFile <- tryCatch(read.delim(newFilei, header = TRUE, sep = '/'), error=function(e) NULL)
            newFile <- tryCatch(newFile, error=function(e) data.frame())
            newFile <- dplyr::bind_rows(newFile, newFile)
            print(tmpFn[i])
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to get:  [1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/name1.tsv", [1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/name2.tsv", [1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/name3.tsv".  I t sounds as the iteration through the lists of names can not happen inside the iteration through the list of lists.

Comment: Please, can you explain what do you want to achieve with `tryCatch()`?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use nested loop. try this:

```r
# sample data
dataFnsDir <- "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/"
lc <- list()
lc[[1]] <- c("150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt","160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
, "JF_160426_Dep2Plas_ctryp_Gpep_SIDtargFULL__PSMs.txt"       ,"JF_160426_Dep2Plas_tryp_Gpep_SIDtarg-(06)_PSMs.txt"  
)
lc[[2]] <- c(
"150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt"  , "160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt",
"JF_160426_Dep2Plas_ctryp_Gpep_SIDtargFULL__PSMs.txt"    
)
lc[[3]] <- c(
  "150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt",
"160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
)

# actual code
lc.path.v <- paste0(dataFnsDir,unlist(lc))
# maybe this is what you want?

lc.path.v
#> [1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt"  
#> [2] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
#> [3] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/JF_160426_Dep2Plas_ctryp_Gpep_SIDtargFULL__PSMs.txt"      
#> [4] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/JF_160426_Dep2Plas_tryp_Gpep_SIDtarg-(06)_PSMs.txt"       
#> [5] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt"  
#> [6] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
#> [7] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/JF_160426_Dep2Plas_ctryp_Gpep_SIDtargFULL__PSMs.txt"      
#> [8] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt"  
#> [9] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
```

If you want to read all of them and combine them together, try this(it may not work because I don't know what the data looks like):

```r
lc.alldf <- lapply(lc.path, read.delim, header = TRUE, sep = "/")
lc.onedf <- dplyr::bind_rows(lc.alldf)
```

**Edit:**
code improved, thanks! @Onyambu

Comment: what is the purpose of `lapply`?? Why not do `paste0(dataFnsDir,unlist(lc))`??

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I think I need this: 
         lapply(
           lc, 
           function(lc) {
             filenames <- file.path(dataFnsDir, lc)
             lapply(filenames, fread) %>% 
               rbindlist(fill = TRUE)
           }
         )  because it produces 3 lists, but on the mean time I would like for the files to each list to be rbound  to make  a single file (total 3 files)  with the names name1.tsv, name2.tsv, name3.tsv .  So I guess I would have to apply the bind_rows command to each group.  Does that sound riwght?

Comment: This would be the output: after the files in each group are combined, renamed and written to the renamed files. [1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/name1.tsv"

[[1]]
[1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/name2.tsv"

[[1]]
[1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/name3.tsv"

Comment: This is what i have done so far;     lapply(
               lc, 
               function(x) {
                 filenames <- file.path(dataFnsDir, x)
                 tryCatch(
                 lapply(filenames, fread )%>% 
                   dplyr::bind_rows(rbindlist(fill = TRUE)), error = function(e) data.frame())
                   lapply(filenames, read.delim, header = TRUE, sep = "/")
               }
             )
         What I wonder is whether all the files are combined or whether the files in each group are combined separately

Comment: I tried this code     lapply(
               lc, 
               function(lc) {
                 filenames <- file.path(dataFnsDir, lc)
                 lapply(filenames, fread )%>% 
                   rbindlist(fill = TRUE)
                   print(tryCatch( dplyr::bind_rows(filenames, read.delim, header = TRUE, sep = "/"), error = function(e) data.frame()))
                   
               }
             )and what I get as a result is data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows

Comment: This works: it merge [1].[2],[3],[4]          [1],[2], [3]         [1],[2]  into 3 separate merges.    datalist= lapply(filenames, function (x) read.delim(file=x, header=TRUE))
                    Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y), datalist)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to create 3 new files each from the file names given as character vectors in each list element.

The main issue with OP's code is that `newFile` is overwritten in each iteration of the nested loops.

Here is what I would with my preferred tools (untested):

```
library(data.table)   # for fread() and rbindlist()
library(magrittr)   # use piping for clarity
lapply(
  lc, 
  function(x) {
    filenames <- file.path(dataFnsDir, x)
    lapply(filenames, fread) %>% 
      rbindlist()
  }
)
```

This will return a list of three dataframes (data.tables).

I do not have the OP's input files available but we can simulate the effect for demonstration. If we remove  the second call to `lapply()` we will get a list of 3 elements each containing a character vector of file names with the path prepended.

```
lapply(
  lc, 
  function(x) {
    filenames <- file.path(dataFnsDir, x)
    print(filenames)
  }
)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt"
>
> [2] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
> [3] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/JF_160426_Dep2Plas_ctryp_Gpep_SIDtargFULL__PSMs.txt"
>
> [4] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/JF_160426_Dep2Plas_tryp_Gpep_SIDtarg-(06)_PSMs.txt"
>
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt"
>
> [2] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
> [3] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/JF_160426_Dep2Plas_ctryp_Gpep_SIDtargFULL__PSMs.txt"
>
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt"
>
> [2] "/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA/160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
> ```

#### Data

```
dataFnsDir <-"/home/giuseppa/Development/glycoPipeApp/OUT/openMS/INPUT_DATA"
lc <- list(
  c("150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt",
    "160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt",
    "JF_160426_Dep2Plas_ctryp_Gpep_SIDtargFULL__PSMs.txt",
    "JF_160426_Dep2Plas_tryp_Gpep_SIDtarg-(06)_PSMs.txt"
  ),
  c(
    "150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt"  ,
    "160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt",
    "JF_160426_Dep2Plas_ctryp_Gpep_SIDtargFULL__PSMs.txt"
  ),
  c(
    "150413_JF_GPeps_SIDtarg_GPstdMix_Tryp_2runs_v3_PSMs.txt",
    "160824_JF_udep_tryp_Hi_SIDdda_FULL_NewParse-(05)_PSMs.txt"
  )
)
```